# Spring and Jackson Integration

Tags: java, json, spring

I am getting this exception while returning Java class at JSON object using JacksonMapper.

org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class $Proxy57 and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: java.util.HashMap["exception"]->org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException["targetType"]->org.springframework.core.convert.TypeDescriptor["annotations"])

```
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider$1.serialize(StdSerializerProvider.java:55)

at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.ArraySerializers$ObjectArraySerializer.serialize(ArraySerializers.java:66)

at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.ArraySerializers$ObjectArraySerializer.serialize(ArraySerializers.java:35)

at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:218)

at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:122)

at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:218)

at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:122)

at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.MapSerializer.serializeEntries(MapSerializer.java:131)

at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:74)

at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:19)

at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:260)

at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:212)

at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:694)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView.renderMergedOutputModel(MappingJacksonJsonView.java:151)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1063)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:801)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)

at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)

at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)

at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)

at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)

at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)

at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:343)

at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)

at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)

at org.springframework.security.oauth.provider.OAuthProviderProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuthProviderProcessingFilter.java:173)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)

at org.springframework.security.oauth.provider.OAuthProviderProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuthProviderProcessingFilter.java:193)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)

at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)

at org.springframework.security.oauth.provider.OAuthProviderProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuthProviderProcessingFilter.java:193)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)

at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)

at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)

at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)

at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:112)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)

at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)

at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)

at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)

at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)

at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)

at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)

at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:109)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)

at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:109)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)

at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)

at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)

at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:206)

at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:179)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:776)
at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:705)
at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:898)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I want to know for which class $Proxy57 object is creating by Spring so that i can debug my code and also very rare i found this error on server. So i didn't get the proper cause for this. This exception cause my server crash sometime.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Generically, that error means that Jackson doesn't know how to serialize that kind of object.
Are you using any ORM like Hibernate?

ORM's and alikes usually create proxy classes in order to be able to "lazy load" the data. The cause might be something similar.

Comment: Yes Sir, i am using iBatis as ORM.

Comment: but I m not getting the cause of this JacksonMappingException and for which class $Proxy57 object is created

Answer (score 2):

When you use an ORM it creates Proxy Objects from the objects you persist. This way it can *lazy load* (i.e, load only when needed) the information through that proxy. Jackson doesn't know how to serialize these proxies, just normal POJOs. Often, when you pass the objects to jackson, the ORM session has already been closed and the lazy loading attempt fails. I'm convinced that the fact that you're trying to serialize an ORM proxy object is the root cause of your problem.

One solution is to disable lazy loading in your ORM. Of course, you will lose all the benefits from lazy loading. Think carefully what you *lazy load* and what you don't (If you use JPA, which I strongly advise, explicitly annotate your POJO relations).

Another solution is to write a custom Jackson serializer that knows how to serialize these kind of objects.

I've had the same problems with hibernate and this [little module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-hibernate) did just that: my Jackson now serializes Hibernate specific objects and datatypes.